# How To Optimize PostgreSQL generate_series function

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a query that uses PostgreSQL generate_series function but when it comes to large amounts of data, the query can be slow. An example of code the generates the query is below:

```
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d',(strtotime ( '-1 day' ) ));


            $query = "
            WITH interval_step AS (
            SELECT gs::date AS interval_dt, random() AS r 
            FROM generate_series('$yesterday'::timestamp, '2015-01-01', '1 day') AS gs)
            SELECT articles.article_id, article_title, article_excerpt, article_author, article_link, article_default_image, article_date_published, article_bias_avg, article_rating_avg
            FROM development.articles JOIN interval_step ON articles.article_date_added::date=interval_step.interval_dt ";

            if (isset($this -> registry -> get['category'])) {
                $query .= "
                JOIN development.feed_articles ON articles.article_id = feed_articles.article_id
                JOIN development.rss_feeds ON feed_articles.rss_feed_id = rss_feeds.rss_feed_id
                JOIN development.news_categories ON rss_feeds.news_category_id = news_categories.news_category_id
                WHERE news_category_name = $1";

                $params = array($category_name);
                $query_name = 'browse_category';
            }

            $query .= " ORDER BY interval_step.interval_dt DESC, RANDOM() LIMIT 20;";
```

This series looks for only content that goes one day back and sorts the results in random order. My question is what are was that generate_series can be optimized to improve performance?

Comment: Creating a "calendar" table with proper indexes is probably your best choice.

Comment: Can describe what would be a "calendar" table?

Comment: It's a table that contains "all" possible dates (e.g. from 1900-01-01 up to 2100-01-01). You then (outer) join against that table rather than creating the dates "on the fly" as you do with generate_series(). To create the table you would use `generate_series()`. Btw: for "pure" SQL problems it's much better to remove the programming language "noise" from your question and only post the generated SQL statement.

Comment: Also: look at the execution plan of your generated query to make sure it is indeed the `generate_series()` function that makes your query slow. More hints on how to ask a performance question can be found in the Postgres Wiki: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: Without `RIGHT` this `JOIN` is equivalent to a range-search :: `where articles.artival_date >= 'yesterday':: date and a.article_date_added < '2015-0-01'`. IOW: you dont need the calendar-CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that `generate_series` at all. And do not concatenate query strings. Avoid it by making the parameter an empty string (or null) if it is not set:

```
if (!isset($this -> registry -> get['category']))
    $category_name = '';

$query = "
    select articles.article_id, article_title, article_excerpt, article_author, article_link, article_default_image, article_date_published, article_bias_avg, article_rating_avg
    from
        development.articles
        inner join
        development.feed_articles using (article_id)
        inner join
        development.rss_feeds using (rss_feed_id)
        inner join
        development.news_categories using (news_category_id)
    where
        (news_category_name = $1 or $1 = '')
        and articles.article_date_added >= current_date - 1
    order by
        date_trunc('day', articles.article_date_added) desc,
        random()
    limit 20;
";

$params = array($category_name);
```

Passing `$yesterday` to the query is also not necessary as it can be done entirely in SQL.

If `$category_name` is empty it will return all categories:

```
(news_category_name = $1 or $1 = '')
```

Comment: Looks like I still have a few things to learn about SQL and Postgres. I've never seen the 'using' in a join.

Answer (score 1):

Imho, try removing that `random()` in your `order by` statement. It probably has a much larger performance impact than you think. As things are it's probably ordering the entire set by `interval_dt desc, random()`, and then picking the top 20. Not advisable...

Try fetching e.g. 100 rows ordered by `interval_dt desc` instead, then shuffle them per the same logic, and pick 20 in your app. Or wrap the entire thing in a subquery `limit 100`, and re-order accordingly along the same lines.

Comment: Random ordering is required. The results are aggregated from sources that I do not have control off nor how many come from a source. So 100 could come in from one source. Random is used for one day to try make article delivered in the morning also have a chance of being seen in the evening, hence why the interval is set to one day.

Comment: That just made me think, if the time span is 1 day, I probably do not need interval_step.interval_dt DESC and might be able to give RANDOM more CPU in the config.

Comment: Whichever you do, my key point is that it (imho) the part of your query that is devastating from a performance standpoint is `random()`, rather than `generate_series()`. Pick your rows first, *then* order by random. Whether you order by random at the app level or at the db level makes little difference if you've a few hundred rows to consider. But as things stand, methinks you're ordering a lot more rows than you should.